# No me abre el modal que esta de manera dinamica

Tags: php

Mi modal no me abre de forma dinamica(php) que esta con jquery, el codigo del boton que activa el modal esta de la siguiente forma.

```
$botones = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning 
btnEditarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#modalEditarProducto'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button> 
</div>";
```

y como esta el html del modal es:

```
<div id="modalEditarProducto" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
```

OJO-NO ME SALE NINGUN ERROR, SOLO NO ME DEJA ABRIR EL MODAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente te falte por añadir el `<script>` de bootstrap que es el que le da la funcionalidad a la modal. Yo he probado a recrear tu cógido y me funciona bien.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Tu botón de editar -->

<button class='btn btn-warning 
btnEditarProducto' data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#modalEditarProducto'>Editar</button>

<!-- La modal -->

<div id="modalEditarProducto" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Editar</h5>
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Es esto lo que buscas?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="finishWorkspace" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Si</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: listo, "ya se abre el modal" nada mas que en vez de que aparezca el contenido, me sale solo lo negro que esta afuera del modal. Es mas intente abrir con el boton otro modal que ya tenia y que si abre bien, y ese lo abre de manera correcta.